# Using Perl to remove sections based on a string search?

Tags: regex, string, perl, search, pos

For data sets similar to the following:

```
<label, someoption=true>
<variable1>
<variable2>
</label>
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
</label>
<label, someoption=true>
<variable1>
<variable2>
<variable3>
</label>
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
<variable2>
<variable3>
</label>
```

Which variables (1, 2, 3 above) appears is inconsistent. I would like it to get rid of the  sections in which it finds:

```
someoption=true
```

to return:

```
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
</label>
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
<variable2>
<variable3>
</label>
```

Please let me know if additional details are helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<label, someoption=true>` The comma in here after the tag, makes this invalid html. It would be better if the tags were valid html, otherwise you have to explain a crap load of stuff to match this. Sort of like going down the rabbit hole. Without the comma, you could do this `<([\w:]+)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\ssomeoption=false)\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>` and get _label_ tag to be used in the closure part `[\S\s]*?</\1\s*.`

Comment: What have you tried? Please tell us what issues you are having.

Answer (score 3):

If the file can fit into memory, you can try command line Perl

```
perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(<label.+?<\/label>)/gs ) 
   { $x=$1; print "$x\n" if $x!~/someoption\s*=\s*true/ } ' file
```

with your given inputs,

```
$ cat metaditch.xml
<label, someoption=true>
<variable1>
<variable2>
</label>
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
</label>
<label, someoption=true>
<variable1>
<variable2>
<variable3>
</label>
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
<variable2>
<variable3>
</label>
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /(<label.+?<\/label>)/gs ) 
       { $x=$1; print "$x\n" if $x!~/someoption\s*=\s*true/ } ' metaditch.xml
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
</label>
<label, someoption=false>
<variable1>
<variable2>
<variable3>
</label>
$
```

Comment: @zdim.. I have one question.. how to read a file in binary mode and print each byte in hexadecimal .. in a perl one-liner

Comment: @zdim.. yep.. cleaned up

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the output you demonstrate reading from standard input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $start=0;
my $label="label";  #Set the label text here
my $options="someoption"; #Set the option text here
my $value="false";  #Set the option value here
while (<>) {
    if ( /\Q$label, $options=$value/) {
        $start=1;
        print $_;
        next;
    }
    if ($start == 1) {
        print $_;
    }
    if (/\/$label/) {
        $start=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: or using good  old sed for a one liner to do the same `sed -ne '/<label, someoption=false/, /<\/label>/p' < intput.txt`

Comment: Or if you want to stick with Perl, your one-liner is `perl -ne 'print unless /<label, someoption=true/ .. /<\/label>/'`

Comment: @Dada that is a much nicer solution

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the input, one line at a time.  If the current line matches `<label, someoption=true>`, skip it and every line up to and including the next line that contains `</label>`.  Otherwise, print it and every line up to and including the next line that contains `</label>`.  Or you could get fancy and use one of the many XML processing Perl modules, but that doesn't appear necessary.

Comment: This answer basically says "To remove some lines, just remove those lines". I fail to see how this is helpful.

Comment: Nonsense.  It's a description the algorithm required to get the job done.  If I'd posted a code sample, would you have the same complaint?

Comment: As Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, this answer seems sufficient given the information provided.

Comment: I like this one a lot actually. It's a better than the general approach I was taking (indexing and printing based on combined locations of someoption=true and /label).

Comment: @PaulM. Allright, seems that while this answer sounded very obvious an unhelpful to me, it was actually useful to the OP. If you edit it, I'll remove my downvote (no need to change anything, just edit it: a downvote can be undone unless the answer is edited). Sorry about that, seems like you were right :)